# Simplification of $\log_2(1-l)/\log_2(1-2^{nH(m/n)-n})$

Tags: algorithms

I am simplifying a big formula to find the big notation of a certain algorithm. The expression is:

$$\log_2(1-l)/\log_2(1-2^{nH(m/n)-n})$$

where $0.98<l< 1$, $0<m<n/2$, $n>0$ and $H$ is the binary entropy function.

In practice, I known that the algorithm is exponential, but I do not known how simplify that to get the exponential expression. Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean simplifying to big-oh notation or exact simplification?

Comment: to big notation

Comment: As a function of $n$?  As a function of both $m$ and $n$?  What's wrong with the expression you already have?  That looks like it's already an answer to your question.

Comment: @D.W. as function of $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Try using the estimate $\log (1-x) = -x-O(x^2)$, valid for $x$ bounded away from 1.